# Access Banked Registers in AArch32

Tags: assembly, arm, interrupt, armv7

I'm wondering how does one go about accessing the banked registers such as sp_irq, sp_fiq, etc.

The ARM v8 ARM describes describes an encoding for MRS/MSR instructions which allows the programmer to access these register directly, but for some reason `MSR sp_irq, r0` doesn't compile as the register name is not recognized.

Is there some compiler option I'm missing, am I using the wrong syntax, or is what I'm doing not even possible?

Comment: Ah, right. You're going to have to expand on the rather unhelpful "doesn't seem to work", though. Do you mean you get an error from the assembler? Something else? What toolchain are we even talking about here?

Comment: @Notlikethat Sorry about that, I've updated the question.

Comment: The exact error message and, crucially, the actual name of the thing that said it would be more helpful (I can think of at least 6 different ARM assemblers off the top of my head, only two of which I have any familiarity with). In the case of a GNU toolchain, if the error _isn't_ "Error: Banked registers are not available with this architecture." then you've either got a horribly old binutils, or the wrong binutils entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question doesn't talk specify the CPU mode (32/64) and no specific compiler, I'll try to answer based on my experience:

AARCH32:
It could be a upper/lower case issue. Try using combinations like **SP_irq**, sp_IRQ, SP_IRQ. I had faced issues on GCC because of this upper/lower case issue.

AARCH64:
The 64 bit GP registers have a direct mapping to 32 bit registers. It is explained in **Register mappings between AArch32 state and AArch64 state** of ARM V8 Architecture Reference Manual.

Eg. SP_irq <==> X17

Hope this helps.